# Autocorrelation of power spectrum

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, autocorrelation

Anyone have an idea of how I can implement autocorrelation of power spectrum of one image? I tried using:

```
 autocorrel = ifft( | fft(power spectrum) | ^ 2 );
```

but it's not working. Do you have any idea why or some other way?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you sure you want the autocorrelation of the power spectrum, or do you want the autocorrelation of the image itself?

Answer (score 6):

The autocorrelation function is the inverse Fourier Transform 
of the power spectrum. I have no idea where you got your formula
from or what your calculation is 
meant to be doing. Are you sure that you are reading the 
book/journal article/application note/website/Wikipedia or whatever
correctly?

In any case, if you want to compute an autocorrelation
as an `ifft`, you should be careful about making sure that
the power spectrum vector is set up right. If the 
autocorrelation function that you compute as the iffy
does not have a peak at the origin (or as the first
entry in the vector for MATLABi folks) and have the
symmetry property $R[i] = R[-i]$ in real life and
the appropriately translated version in MATLAB, something
is awry.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I found this formula somewhere on the internet. Its based on Wiener–Khinchin theorem where auto-correlation of one image is multiplication of fft of that image.
But, Im getting central peak, and result is symmetric but it looks like values of data is wrong, and that is a reason because I want to check formula first..